# What do feature phones do if there isn't any CSS?

Tags: responsive-design

In the past, I've created a "global" style sheet that all browsers and devices that support CSS should be able to receive.

The problem with that is that my old Nokia understood background image but the screen was so bad that the background images made the website look awful.

I then started putting any background images inside a CSS file with a media query so that old phones like this wouldn't understand it. However, this creates a lot more work. So I've started putting "global.css" behind a media query. The idea is that if the phone isn't capable of understanding media queries I don't want it to read my style sheet. Older (desktop) versions of IE are still served the CSS using conditional comments.

SO my question is, if a phone doesn't understand the CSS, would it provide its own fall back just like a desktop browser does? So at least a h1 is bigger than h2 etc and the text isn't all lumped in one huge block?

I'm guessing this could be a "It depends" answer but I'd appreciated feedback on this. I don't have my old nokia to hand so can't see what that is doing at the moment.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It does depend on lots of factors, such as vendor and how old the device is. However, in my experience generally they do render h1's bigger than normal text; can't say the same for h2's of further down the h's, though.

Usually for old mobile sites (back when XHTML-MP was the new thing and WML was all the rage) we used to set font sizes with CSS using these font-size values:

```
xx-small, x-small, small, medium, large, x-large and xx-large
```

From my experience, I can tell you that only `small, medium and large` work reliably across most feature phone mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

All Nokia browsers (including the old XHTML MP versions) did include a default style sheet. This included basic styling for all the headers, a basic bullet and default bullet margins for lists and a bold and italic style. The various headers were not always that well differentiated but they was enough of a difference that one was discernable from another. The only real gotcha was with italicised text. There was often no italicised font per se so the browser would shift each character's pixels to the right to simulate a slanted font. This often resulted in poor legibility.